# Mesh not reflecting light in unreal engine

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4, light

I'm working with a photogrametry mesh (.fbx) that I have cleaned up in blender 2.8.

In UE (4.26), when I build the light, the mesh goes dark (as on the pic).

I do have a UV generated in blender.
In UE, the mesh has a 256 light map resolution & a light map coordinate index of 1.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

before building light
[image]

After building light
[image]

UV mapping in blender
[image]

UV channel 0
[image]

UV channel 1 (this is what I suspect is the problem but I have no solution)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I just needed to put 0 as the light map coordinate index value